# Tablesorter: set a widget option to true for one column and false for another.

Tags: tablesorter

I'm trying to figure out how to set **filter_startsWith: true** for one column, and **false** for another column. In the case of one of my tables, I have an int column and a varchar column. The int column needs to be sorted with **filter_startsWith: true**. The varchar column needs **filter_startsWith: false**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [`filter_startsWith` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-startswith) applies to all columns. It would not be too difficult to alter the plugin code to make it work per column; I will add this to my "to do" list.

If you want to set a default filter which always applies to a column, and prevents other filter types from working properly, then you can set the [`filter_defaultFilter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-defaultfilter) to use regex to target a specific column ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4743/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_defaultFilter : {
                2: '/^{query}/'
            }
        }
    });
});
```